# Python ImportError: cannot import name urlencode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've seen this question asked before but none of the answers seem to work for me.
I am using python version 2.7.13
In my code I have ..

```
import base64
import httplib2
```

Now when I run it on my own pc it works fine, but when I run it on my works p.c. behind a firewall I get ..

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "mail4.py", line 2, in
>
> import httplib2
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line 39, in
>
> import urllib
>
> File "C:\mypy\urllib.py", line 1, in
>
> import requests
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests__init__.py", line 43, in
>
> import urllib3
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3__init__.py", line 8, in
>
> from .connectionpool import (
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 35, in
>
> from .request import RequestMethods>
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 10, in >
>
> from .packages.six.moves.urllib.parse import urlencode
>
> ImportError: cannot import name urlencode

I've tried setting proxies.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing six

Also

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
```

All to no avail ?

Answer (score 1):

You are (in this case) apparently running Python 2.7.x, however `parse` module is in `urllib` package in Python 3.x. In Python 2.x its name was (just) `urlparse`. Based on that, I'd guess different configuration (mismatch in versions used between Code and/or 3rd party packages and/or python interpreter is behind the problem you're seeing).

EDIT: sorry, I should have also noticed you are looking for `urlencode` on the last bit. In python 2.7 that is a function in `urllib` module: `from urllib import urlencode`.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but unfortunately I still get the exact same error.

Comment: Well looking at the backtrace, it's not your code that ran into trouble. This goes beyond Python itself and concerns 3rd party package urllib3 that I am not familiar with... and it looks for urllib.parse inside another package. But this name difference between 2 and 3 is there. So I do suspect there being (probably along the chain of dependencies) mismatch and you have some code expecting py3 running on py2.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with installing Werkzeug to <1.0, which removed the contrib module

```
pip install Werkzeug==0.16.1
```